# Rails foreign key issue in Heroku migrate with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, amazon-web-services, heroku

I am trying to deploy a Rails project with Heroku.

In development I am running the Ruby project on AWS Educate Cloud9 and using Sqlite3 as the database.

I can successfully run the Rails project on AWS and migrations work fine also there

```
$ rails db:migrate
```

In Production the database is postgres.

This is the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.7', '>= 5.0.7.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
#gem 'sqlite3', '~>1.3.0'
#gem 'devise' , '~>4.3.0'

gem 'devise', git: 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise' #, ref: '88e9a85'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'sqlite3', '~>1.3.0'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  
end

group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Using,

```
$ bundle update
$ bundle install --without production
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "blah"
$ git push origin master
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku run rails db:migrate
```

This gives an error which tells me that there is an issue with a foreign key, but when I `db:migrate` in development there is no issue with a foreign key. I only seem to get this error when I migrate in Heroku using 'pg'.

[image]

Comment: Seems like it's the order of the migration files? Are you creating the orders table after another table that is referencing orders?

Comment: Ok so the order that these are created in is important.

Comment: Yes, but it should have been the same in Sqlite3 - if you reference the table orders it has to be created first.

Comment: Right I will look into that. Thanks

Comment: @Clara yes that is true and the real problem is that it works for sqlite3 in development but but not for 'pg' in production

Comment: BTW, the error doesn't tell you there's an issue with a foreign key. The error states: `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "orders" does not exist`. This error is occurring during the `CreateOrderItems_20200407174144` migration. As @Clara points out, this migration is trying to reference the `orders` table (relation), but (as the error states) the `orders` relation doesn't exist. So, yes, probably an ordering problem.

Comment: How do I set the order in which the migrations are created?

Comment: @ShaneG they are typically ordered the same order as they were generated.

Comment: And what decides the order in which they are generated?

Comment: The migrations appears to be performed in the order of their time stamps https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/16/ruby-on-rails-order-of-migration-generator-matters-in-initial-design/

Comment: So how can I change the timestamp on a migration?

Comment: The order in which you typed the `rails g model` or `rails g migration` commands in the console determines the order in which migrations were generated as reflected by their timestamps (e.g., `20200407174144`). The order in which the migrations were generated is also the order in which the migrations are run. BTW, you might want to look into `rails db:schema:load` - it's worth knowing the difference between migrating and schema loading.

Comment: So the time stamp is actually in the name of the file and I can change it by simply renaming that part of the file for example from 20200412190315_create_orders.rb to something like 20200412190000_create_orders.rb would be resetting the timestamp to 3 minutes 15 seconds earlier. Is that correct? Is it that simple?

Comment: Yes. The file name decides the order the migrations are run in. That is why the timestamp is added by the generator. Also I would really recommend that you start developing on Postgres as well once you're doing actual work. There are very real differences and you don't want to discover them after you have pushed to production.

Comment: Yes, it's that simple. You'll need to be attentive in changing the timestamp not to create new ordering issues. But, if your migrations are not very complex, that may not be much of a challenge. Also, probably better to avoid time hopping into the future.

Comment: @max yes indeed good advice thanks